# Facebook integration login and Googleplus integration login not working after proguard apk (release apk)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0, android-proguard

```
my app proguard-rules.pro file give following code


-keep class com.facebook.android.*
-keep class android.webkit.WebViewClient
-keep class * extends android.webkit.WebViewClient
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.webkit.WebViewClient {
    <methods>;
}

-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe
-dontwarn com.google.common.collect.MinMaxPriorityQueue

-keepattributes *Annotation*,Signature

-keep class * extends com.google.api.client.json.GenericJson {
*;
}

-keep class com.google.api.services.drive.** {
*;
}
```

how to solve this problem? 
    I have an Android application that allows the user login based on facbook  login and Googleplus login .
   All this is perfectly working with the debug build

When testing the  proguard  (release ) version of the application, that time not working both logins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add facebook oauth keys for release version on [facebook site](https://developers.facebook.com). Also you should know when you publicate your app on play store google can resign release version and you will have to add new oauth key.
Your proguard file is not a reason of your problem.
For google-plus you should also add a oAuth key for release version.

To solve google release bug try to add new credentials in https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library site. Choose your project on left top corner, tap menu & choose "APIs & Services" -> credentials. After that create OAuth client ID for Android.
Then run this code
`keytool -exportcert -keystore path-to-debug-or-production-keystore -list -v`
where put path to your release keystore. Also don't forget about package name. After thaht manipulation your google+ authorization must work!

Comment: If you have any questions - feel free to ask me.

Comment: @krishna does it helps for you?

Comment: thanks for ur reply. how add facebook oauth keys for release version? any sample link. i already registered fb

Comment: You can give me your contacts (email, facebook, telegram, etc.) and I will write you details.

Comment: On your developer facebook account (https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{your_app_code}/fb-login/quickstart/) on 4th step (where creating hash-keys). For getting this key you can run this command: keytool -exportcert -alias YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS -keystore YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_PATH | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64. Or use other way to get hash key of realese version.

Comment: thanks @sasha  i already registered but problem now only saw. there choosing one option i missed. But google not yet solved.

Comment: my email id krishtech.developer@gmail.com

Comment: facebook issue also repeat. but normal build app both working

Comment: @krishna I have changed my answer with including google+ solution. Please check it!

Comment: Thanks i solved issues. actually problem is key. normal debug time create key and sign app create key is differ

Comment: "You should add facebook oauth keys" - this meams that your keys different and you must create key for release version) I think you check my answer like that to help to solve your problem

Comment: Thanks Bro @Sasha . you have any idea about this issue ? really struggle    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50280428/how-to-list-pdf-file-fro-external-device-and-upload-to-server-for-latest-android